# How to update a given parent child from within another child WITHOUT using parent state to prevent rerendering of the children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent with 2 children: one of the children is a button that serves to go to the next panel.
The other children is a panel (among many) that holds its own specific states.
The overal layout is to hide the panel-specific complexity from the parent. But whenever the panel child is ready to pass to the next panel, it has to tell to the next button.

The reason why I don't want to use useState in the parent is to prevent a global rerendering and the loose of the complex state the panel synthesised.

I know I can achieved this by using a key on the button but I did not manage to do it.

I prepared a "sandbox" for this, that can be forked from here : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-scroll-to-forked-3vbev?file=/index.js

The code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

/**
 * @summary The HOC component that displays a series of panel that the user can reach by clicking on NEXT buttun
 */
function Page() {
  const enabled = useRef(false);

  const onSetEnabled = useCallback(() => {
    enabled.current = true;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Panel tellToEnableButton={onSetEnabled} />
      <NextButton key={""+enabled.current} enabled={enabled.current} />
    </div>
  );
}

/**
 * @summary The button on which the user click to pass to the next panel
 * @param {boolean} enabled True to enable the button
 */

function NextButton({ enabled }) {
  return (
    <button disabled={enabled ? undefined : "disabled"}>NEXT PANEL</button>
  );
}

/**
 * @summary A complex UI/UX that must tell when the HOC must let the user pass to the next panel
 * @param {{tellToEnableButton: function}} tellToEnableButton The call back to call to enable the NEXT button
 */
function Panel({ tellToEnableButton }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        Complex panel with its own complex state and logic that must tel when
        it's ready to pass to next panel
      </p>
      <button onClick={tellToEnableButton}>
        Tell HOC to set NEXT button enabled
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

render(<Page />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: fwiw `HOC` here may lead to confusion to readers. I don't see any HOC (Higher-Order Component) here, only a parent component. a HOC is a function that takes a component and returns a new one with enhanced properties.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the description

Comment: There is no React mechanism to communicate between sibling components. You might use something like redux (which is effectively like a "global variable"), but I would try to find out why the panel loses any state, not to avoid the parent rendering. (Note that by saying "rendering" here I mean the component gets recomputed, not the DOM render.)